# Why Legend's text in Nivo Bar Charts doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, charts, nivo-react

I am trying to use this library for charts in React:
https://nivo.rocks/

I have copied the [exact same example in the docs](https://nivo.rocks/bar/) for the horizontal column chart (bar chart) but on my env, the legends are simply not shown.

I have looked for all other issues previously posted concerning labels not showing up and legend's problems troubleshoot. But this is a different issue. it just doesn't work as expected / as shown in the documentation live preview

CodeSandbox showing the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/missing-legends-text-pns6v

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `div` tag that looks like this:

```
<div style={{ width: "80%", height: "400px", color: "white" }}>
```

The colour is set to white. Remove that, and the text will display.